# How can I detect a jqGrid has been resized?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I can find no event for when a user resizes a jqGrid with the mouse. I.e. when 'gridResize' set.

Is there some way to add a custom event?

Comment: Check `resizeStart` and `resizeStop`: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: |They only work for manual column resizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid creates some outer divs over the main table element. The method `gridResize` uses jQuery UI Resizable on the most outer div, so named **gbox**. Thus you can register resizable event `resizestop` on the gbox to detect the end of resizing. The corresponding code will looks like the following:

```js
...
$grid.jqGrid("gridResize");
...
$grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").bind("resizestop", function () {
    alert("grid is resized");
});
```